# Returning a collection of pointers by value

Tags: c++

I have a library function that creates and returns (by value) a vector of pointers to some objects on the heap. This works well and good when I'm using c++ but now I need to export this function so that it can be linked with C and I'm confused on how to achieve this in a clean way.

My first naïve attempt was the following:

```
airport_t **listAiportsByCode(const char *code) {
    vector<airport_handle*> airports;
    // Fill up vector with pointer to airports on the heap ...
    airports.push_back(nullptr); 
    airport_t** c_airports = airports.data();
    return c_airports;
}
```

which obviously won't work since the airports vector is stack allocated.

Do I need to allocate an array on the heap and simply document that the array needs to be deleted after use?

```
airport_t **listAiportsByIATA(const char *iata) {
    vector<airport_handle*> airports;
    // Fill up vector with airports ...
    airports.push_back(nullptr);
    airport_t* c_airports = new airport_t*[BUFFER];
    std::copy(airports.begin(), airports.end(), c_airports);
    return c_airports;
}
```

I'm used to programming in high level languages and this seems to mee as a too ugly design for such a trivial function.

Comment: Looks plausible, although your array size `BUFFER` should really be `airports.size()`. Oh, and there's no reason not to use `std::unique_ptr<airport_t[]>` _inside_ your function - just `release` it on return.

Comment: C is included in the tags.  Are you interested in how this might be done using C as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dealing with the memory I think your only options are to allocate the array and have the client tidy it up or have the client allocate the array.

It also might be cleaner to not use a vector and write directly into the array?

Allocating array for the client:

```
airport_t **listAiportsByIATA(const char *iata) {

    airport_t** c_airports = new airport_t*[BUFFER];

    // Fill up vector with airports ...
    for (airport_t** airport = c_airports; airport < c_airports + BUFFER; ++airport) {
        *airport = nullptr;
    }

    return c_airports;
}
```

Client allocates array:

```
void listAiportsByIATA(const char *iata, airport_t ** c_airports, int maxSize) {

    // Fill up vector with airports ...
    for (airport_t** airport = c_airports; airport < c_airports + maxSize; ++airport) {
        *airport = nullptr;
    }

}
```

Comment: When using your first suggestion, can the client call free on the c_airports array after using it? I've heard that it can cause problem calling free on pointers allocated with new (not malloc) and vice versa. Should I allocate the array with malloc instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have used malloc given we're talking about C. You need to use free with malloc and delete [] with new [].

Answer (score 2):

It is quite ugly, but that is the C way of doing things. 
You could either take your approach, or get an airport_t** as a parameter and have the client allocate memory for you.
You would only need to fill the client allocated memory, and return the number of elements inserted.

```
int listAiportsByIATA(const char *iata, airport_t **c_airports) {
    vector<airport_handle*> airports;
    // Fill up vector with airports ...
    airports.push_back(nullptr);
    std::copy(airports.begin(), airports.end(), c_airports);
    return airports.size();
}
```

this solution however will have another problem, the client will need to allocate enough memory for you to fill. So you probably want to add another check.